# undefined TypeError only on iPhone -- JavaScript, HTML5 canvas_context.measureText

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, undefined, typeerror

I'm having an issue when running a webpage on iOS Safari.

I am using the [canvas-text library](http://code.google.com/p/canvas-text/) to render text which works perfectly on the following:

- Ubuntu/Windows -- chrome, firefox
- Mac -- Safari
- Android -- default, firefox, opera,
  dolphin

However, it does not work on **iPhone**.

I enabled the javascript console on the iPhone and I get a few errors which read :

> Javascript: Error undefined
>
> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

The console does not display line numbers, but by placing alert boxes throughout the code I was able to isolate where the problem occured. Here is the code which produces the error:

```
usedX = context.measureText(textUsername).width + context.measureText(textInput).width + paddingInput*2 + borderInput*2;
```

The problem exists within context.measureText. I know this because I have tried replacing the previous code with the following:

```
var usedX = context.measureText("why is this an error?");
```

and I still got the error on that line.

I know for sure that context and measureText are defined because I have done:

```
alert(context.measureText);
```

which alerted:

> function measureText(){[native code]}

As I said, the problem seems to be in measureText. I have Googled lot's and could not find a solution.

I am a JavaScript noob, so I won't be all that surprised if there is a simple fix. But it seems all is well with the code, and this is a problem with iPhone's implementation of measureText.